# Optimize in R on dataframe

Tags: r, optimization

Hi I have this dataset:

```
> structure(list(leng = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 
900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 
100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 
300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 
500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 
900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 
100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 
300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 
500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 
900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 
100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 
300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 
500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 
700, 800, 900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 
900, 1000, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000), 
    flow = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
    30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
    60, 60, 60, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 80, 80, 
    80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 
    90, 90, 90, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 120, 
    120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 130, 130, 130, 
    130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 
    140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
    150, 150, 150, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 160, 
    160, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 180, 
    180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 190, 190, 190, 
    190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 190, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
    200, 200, 200, 200, 200), diam = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2)), out.attrs = list(dim = c(leng = 10L, flow = 20L, 
diam = 1L), dimnames = list(leng = c("leng= 100", "leng= 200", 
"leng= 300", "leng= 400", "leng= 500", "leng= 600", "leng= 700", 
"leng= 800", "leng= 900", "leng=1000"), flow = c("flow= 10", 
"flow= 20", "flow= 30", "flow= 40", "flow= 50", "flow= 60", "flow= 70", 
"flow= 80", "flow= 90", "flow=100", "flow=110", "flow=120", "flow=130", 
"flow=140", "flow=150", "flow=160", "flow=170", "flow=180", "flow=190", 
"flow=200"), diam = "diam=2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-200L))
```

And this function

```
> hazwil2= function(diam,flow,leng){
psi2=((1/(2.31*100))*1050*((flow/140)^1.852)*leng*diam^-4.87)
return(psi2)
}
```

I'm trying to use optimize to minimize psi2 by varying the value of diam. psi2 should be smaller than 3, it doesn't have to be zero.

This works:

```
> optimize(f=hazwil2,interval=c(0.1,12),flow=100,leng=400)
```

but when I try to run the optimize function on the vectors for flow and leng, like this:

```
> optimize(f=hazwil2,interval=c(0.1,12),flow=df2$flow,leng=df2$leng)
```

I get:

> invalid function value in 'optimize'

I tried with apply() but that doesn't seem to work either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Gerry

Comment: Although it's not explicit in the documentation, it seems to me that `optimize` only takes scalar arguments for the variables (flow and leng in your case), and it returns a list of two elements (scalar both): minimum and objective, so passing a vector makes it complain

Comment: Hi PavoDive, thank you for your comment, I agree with you. The question is: how to pass a vector to optimize() instead of a scalar and get a vector of minimums in return ? I tried apply() with no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If `optimize` takes only scalars, I would try with `lapply` or a plain `for`. I'm away of my machine, but if nothing comes, I'll try to help in a few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to solve this:

```
# load library
require(data.table)

# convert data.frame to data.table
setDT(df2)

# create an id column (it will be later removed)
df2[, id := 1:.N]

# Estimate and assign the minimum (output 1 of optimize) 
#      for each flow and leng values:
df2[, minimum := optimize(hazwil2, 
                          interval = c(0.1, 12), 
                          flow, 
                          leng)[[1]], 
       by = id]

# Estimate and assing objective (output 2 of optimize)
#             for each pair of flow and leng:
df2[, objective := optimize(hazwil2, 
                            interval = c(0.1, 12), 
                            flow, 
                            leng)[[2]], 
      by = id]

# remove id column
df2[, id := NULL]

# view df2:
> df2
     leng flow diam  minimum    objective
  1:  100   10    2 11.99994 1.902594e-05
  2:  200   10    2 11.99994 3.805188e-05
  3:  300   10    2 11.99994 5.707782e-05
  4:  400   10    2 11.99994 7.610376e-05
  5:  500   10    2 11.99994 9.512970e-05
 ---                                     
196:  600  200    2 11.99994 2.930926e-02
197:  700  200    2 11.99994 3.419414e-02
198:  800  200    2 11.99994 3.907902e-02
199:  900  200    2 11.99994 4.396390e-02
200: 1000  200    2 11.99994 4.884877e-02
```

Comment: Hi PavoDive, thank you for your answer. Your script works well but I failed to explain what I'm really looking for. I guess I'm not looking for an absolute minimum but for the smallest minimum that will keep the objective below 3. My function is monotonic so it will always result in the largest possible value of diam (within my interval). So I always get a value close to 12 for minimum, that makes the objective as small as possible. Also, I should mention that diam is the diameter of a pipe, so it can only be a discrete values, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. Thanks again. Gerry

Comment: You can write your own function and use it with the code I proposed. If the code is useful for your initial question, you may want to check mine as an answer.